# Account Manager returning empty for com.google

Tags: android, google-play, accountmanager

I am wondering in which cases can an app return an empty array when using

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Accoun[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
return accounts[0].name
```

and return a null (or a null pointer exception)

I ask because my app is available just in the google play store, so they need a google account in order to access it.
So how can the accountmanager return no accounts of type com.google if the app was downloaded from the play store (unless they side loaded it).

Again, the question is what scenarios would cause the am.getAccountsByType("com.google") to return a null or a null pointer exception.

Comment: I think the key here is "unless they side loaded it". Also,it may be  possible to install an app from the Play Store, then remove your Google account, though I have not tried this.

Comment: @CommonsWare I thought that if they removed the main Google account, they also removed the apps that came with it?

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't know if it would cause a difference but Is it possible that a user's account type will be different if they have a gmail account like person@gmail.es ?

Comment: I have never tried to retrieve Google account information from `AccountManager`. I would not expect a change in behavior based on Gmail domain name, but the ways of Google are often mysterious... :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code to check if Google Account is present or not. I use it in my app to check if the account is present or not. This works.

```
public static boolean isGoogleAccountPresent() {

        AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(context);
        for(Account account : manager.getAccounts()) {
            if("com.google".equals(account.type)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: O yea, I do have code like that already present, I just get a null pointer elsewhere when I am trying to md5 the account and it crashes there. My question is mostly for info on when com.google accounts can be empty and still have my google play accounts.

Comment: Have you declared the required permission to access the information?

Comment: yes. It works on all devices that have a google play account. As my question states I am not looking for how to get the account. I am looking at scenarios that cause it to return null for google accounts

Comment: In that case, Commonsware's response seems to be the right one. The apps don't get removed when the google account associated with the Play Store registered account is removed for the free apps at least. How purchased apps are treated when account is removed or switched to a different Google account, this link http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24483/what-happens-with-the-installed-apps-when-you-switch-google-account-on-a-phone gives you some information.